# Incorrect coding with respect to logic written

Tags: c

The program needs to execute until 'q' is pressed. But the below code what I wrote it is only executing whichever case is first and then stops executing further cases. Ex: case 1.if my input is p, q, then only p case is executed, not the q. 
case 2.if my input is g, q, then only g case is executed, not the q.

```
   int main()
    {
        int i,n,cnt;
        char value[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int index; float values,Max;
        int *val;
        bool quit=false;
        float num[10]={1.500, 2.200, 7.300, 9.200, 7.400, 7.500, -8.000, 1.500, 12.000, 0.000};
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            scanf("%c",&value[i]);
            if(value[i]=='r')
            {
                scanf("%d", &index); 
                scanf(", %3f",&values);
            }
            if((value[i] =='p')|(value[i] =='q')|(value[i] =='r')|(value[i] =='g')|(value[i] =='s'))
            {
                cnt++;
            }
        }


      for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)
        { 
            while(!quit)
            {
                 switch(value[i])
                {
                    //printf("Command (p/g/r/s/q):");
                    case 'p':
                    {
                        printf("Command (p/g/r/s/q):");
                        printValues(&num,10);
                        return;
                    }
                    case 'g':
                    {
                        printf("Command (p/g/r/s/q):");
                        Max= largestElement(&num,10);
                        printf("Max=%0.3f",Max);
                        return;
                    }
                    case 'r':
                    {
                        printf("Command (p/g/r/s/q):");
                        replaceElement(&num,index,values);
                        printValues(&num,10);
                       return;
                    }
                    case 's':
                    {
                        printf("Command (p/g/r/s/q):");
                        sortOnValue(&num,10);
                        printValues(&num,10);
                        return;
                    }
                    case'q':
                    {
                        printf("Command (p/g/r/s/q):");
                        quit= true;
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        printf("help");
                        return;
                    }
            }
        }

   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `return` statements cause `main()` to be exited and thus the program to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

*Few problems here.*

1. `for(i=0;i<20;i++)` you are accessing out of bound so your loop should be 
       `for(i=0;i<10;i++)`.
2. You need to add `' '` in the format string to consume new line character (`\n`).

   ```
       `scanf(" %c",&value[i]);`
   ```
3. You are using `|` operator instead of `||` hence your `if` should be.

   ```
        if((value[i] =='p')||(value[i] =='q')||(value[i] =='r')||(value[i] =='g')||(value[i] =='s'))
           {
               cnt++;
           }
   ```
4. You are using `return` instead of `break` in your switch case.

   change this

   ```
              case 'p':
               {
                   printf("Command (p/g/r/s/q):");
                   printValues(&num,10);
                   return;
               }
   ```

   to

   ```
              case 'p':
               {
                   printf("Command (p/g/r/s/q):");
                   printValues(&num,10);
                   break;
               }
   ```
5. Your `while(!quit)` inside the `for` loop is not useful  and will lead to  infinate loop when used `break` statement inside switch case. Hence remove the `while(!quit)` and change your `for` loop as below.

   `for(i=0;i<cnt&&!quit;i++)`

> side note:: It is high time for you
>   [learn-how-to-debug-small-programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: i actually used break in switch before but i was not able to fetch next character as it was exiting from the switch and for loop too. So i tried using return but it is not working too. I did try with the corrections you said but I am not getting expected output which i m willing to get.

Comment: @SumanJain What problems are you facing now? and what output you were expecting?

Comment: unable to execute functionality defined under case 'q' whereas for other cases i am able to do

Comment: @SumanJain Because you are using `return` you should use `break` as I suggested for every switch cases.

Comment: I should use exit whenever i use case 'q' because i want to exit from whole program. Eventhough I used exit, i am unable to execute the code written in case 'q'

Comment: @SumanJain  Can you post the new code in the question as part of update.

Answer (score 0):

Within most of your `case` blocks you probably want `break` rather than `return` to exit the switch.  At the moment you are returning from`main()` and consequently exiting the program. `break` transfers control to the end of the switch and your program can then continue.

The `case 'q'` block would then have a return to exit the program.

Comment: input ---
p
r
4, 4.1
p
q                                                                                                                                                output:Command (p/g/r/s/q):Values:1.500 ,2.200 ,7.300 ,9.200 ,7.400 ,7.500 ,-8.000 ,1.500 ,12.000 ,0.000 .Command (p/g/r/s/q):4.100
Values:1.500 ,2.200 ,7.300 ,9.200 ,4.100 ,7.500 ,-8.000 ,1.500 ,12.000 ,0.000 .help 
   So the problem is instead of quiting whenever i use case q, it is not getting reflected . I did check the elements of the array, it is properly taking 'q' as one of the element.